# Why don't my new activities get recognized when pushing to priv-app? [AOSP]

Tags: android

I am working on a system app which lives in `priv-app`. When I add a new activity in my `AndroidManifest` and push the new apk to priv-app and try to launch that activity with adb shell, I get an `ActivityNotFoundException`. When I take that exact same apk and build it as part of the AOSP image, I can launch that activity with adb shell.

How can I get android to recognize the new manifest when I push the apk to priv-app?

(adb install is not an option in my case for a number of reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reboot after pushing the app to priv-app. There's something about system app manifest changes that don't take effect until after you reboot. You'll notice the same thing with new permissions you add to the manifest.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

please try rebuild or clean your application after that run your application

Comment: Instead of posting this as an answer, start be asking whether he's performed this action, as it seems too obvious